# Вывод оформленных формул, куда и как?

Tags: ms-word, синтаксический-анализ

Задача определить X. Имеем Y = 4 и Z = 2. И знаем что X = Y / Z. - все это задача для расчета.
НАША задача написать программу, которая бы представила оформленным решение этого расчета. В итоге мы должны получить следующее:

X = (Y / Z) = (4 / 2) = 2

Единственное условие чтобы выражения в скобках были представлены не в форме строки, а как выглядит обычная формула, то есть как раз сделать парсинг. Само собой разумеется что за место деления может быть любая операция.

Вопрос в том как это сделать и куда? я думал о том что бы расчет делать в консольной программе а выводить в Word. Но как это сделать не нашел. Что посоветуете?

Comment: если бы тут на форуме давали награду - вопрос недели, ты бы выиграл на этой

Comment: Посоветуем научиться генерить входную цепочку символов для [**MathJax'a**][1] или `TeX'a`.

[1]: http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: Gorets, я тут первый раз, так что не совсем понимая ирония это или нет, но все равно спасибо) 
Котик_хочет_кушать, почитаю, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

- Я бы рекомендовал **LaTeX**, как язык для представления формул. Вы создаёте текстовый файл, из которого LaTex может сделать PDF и ещё много вариантов чего.
- LaTeX - система очень большая и сложная, вам нужна только малая её часть. Если вы не знаете LaTeX и нет времени на его изучение, может быть проще использовать **HTML Math**.

Посмтрите здесь сравнение и примеры: Help:Displaying a formula. TeX vs HTML